# When I Add my data from java code to MYSQL Server its not Accept Null Values, how to Make it to accept Null Values?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
 private void jButtonAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String book1;
    SimpleDateFormat Dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO `book`(`Date`,`Book Title`, `Saled Book`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookstore", "root", "");
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, Dformat.format(jDateChooser1.getDate()));
        pst.setString(2, jTextFieldBookTitle.getText());

        book1 = "Saled Book";
        if (jTextFieldSaledBook.getText().isEmpty()) {
            pst.setNull(3, Types.INTEGER);
        } else {
            pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldSaledBook.getText()));
        }
        pst.executeUpdate();
        // To Refresh JTable
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);
        showTableData();
        clearFields();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserted Data Successfully");
    } 
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Number in Field ");
        
    }
    catch (HeadlessException | SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

this is my database part

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `ID` int(15) AUTO INCREMENT,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Book Title` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Saled Book` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

when I run and enter without a number it says:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MysqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException:Column
> 'Saled Book' cannot null....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand the logic, here is what null value can go into "Saled Book" column

```
if (jTextFieldSaledBook.getText().isEmpty()) {
        pst.setNull(3, Types.INTEGER);
    }
```

To me it says: "if I did not found anything in jTextFieldSaledBook, then set 'Saled Book' value to null". This is where a null value being passed in a "not null" column.

If I get it right, the "Saled book" column is here to store amount of books you've sold (it is of type "int"). So, you need to insert 0 and not null in case if nothing is found in jTextFieldSaledBook.

I assume changing if-then part with something like this

```
    if (jTextFieldSaledBook.getText().isEmpty()) {
        pst.setInt(3, 0);
    }
```

will fix your problem. Please note I'm not a Java developer, so you might need to fix my version of code in order to make it runable

Comment: sorry #ekochergin, it was also  ID INT(15) AUTO_INCREMENT from My Xampp Table Row Column am edited. but it's not working for me. thank you for your advice and see my code, please

Comment: Thanks, @ekochergin, you answered my question. God bless you man